# Access to method who defined in trait from object

Tags: php, oop

Example :

```
trait TaxTools {
function calculateтax ( $price ) {
return self::prop . $price ;
}
}

abstract class Alert{
    const prop = 'value__';

    abstract function limpopo();

}
class Alert2 extends Alert{
    use TaxTools;
   public  function limpopo(){
       // return self::$foo;
       return self::foo;
    }


}

$obj = new Alert2;

echo $obj->calculateтax(8); //value__8
echo '<br>';
echo $obj::calculateтax(8); //value__8

echo '<br>';
echo $obj::limpopo(); //Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'foo'
```

Question : Why we can access to method who defined in trait from object by :: syntax ?

Comment: If you want a static method, then you should create it as a static method

Comment: But as self::foo doesn't exist anywhere in your classes or your traits, then you should expect an error when you try to access it

Answer (score 0):

```
Deprecated: Non-static method Alert2::calculateтax() should not be called statically in ... on line 28 

Deprecated: Non-static method Alert2::limpopo() should not be called statically in ... on line 31
```

It's deprecated error. If you have not turned on showing of deprecated level errors you wolud not see it.

Turn it on.

http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.constants.php